# ERROR when reading READ FILE (txt)

Tags: c, file-io

I am facing trouble doing my readfile for my name and score.

I can read the name but i cant read my score.

So I will be posting up two codes.
one is the full one and the second one is the read file code.

I am trying to save and read the save file for my name and score.

However, I can only save the 'name' and the score forever remains 0.

May I know whats the mistake I made in here?

Read file code:

```
FILE * scoreboard=fopen("scoreboard.txt","");

        fprintf(scoreboard,"%s  %i\t\n",username, score);

        scoreboard = fopen("scoreboard.txt","r");

        printf("\n\n*************List of Previous Players*****************\n");

        if (scoreboard == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nNo scores found.\n");
            }


            while(fscanf(scoreboard,"%s %i",username, &score) == 2)
            {
                printf("Name: %s\t\t",username);
                printf("Scores: %i\n", score);
            }
    fclose(scoreboard);
```

full code:

```
/*CREATED BY:
Name: Tan Xian Yao
Student ID: 4323440
Task: Number Crush
Date started: 31/10/2013
Date finished: 4/12/2013
*/

/*Headers Used*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/*Structure Used*/
typedef struct
{
    int m,n;
    char rows,cols, x, y;

}board;

/*Function 1*/
void disp_welcome_msg()/*Display the Welcome Message for players*/
{


    printf("\n~~~~~~~~~~~WELCOME~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
    printf("\n~~~~~~~~NUMBER CRUSH~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");



}
/*Function 2*/
void disp_ready_msg()/*Display the "Ready" message for player before starting the game*/
{

    printf("\nAre you ready for the EXCITING GAME?\n\n");
    system("pause");
    printf("\n*****ATTENTION******");
    printf("\nPress 2,4,6,8 to release out the BOX\n\n");


}

/*Function 3*/
void board_size(board *Array)/*Give players to choose the size of the board they want*/
{
    printf("\n*********PLEASE READ!!********\n");
    printf("\nExample of board size: (Rows: 19, Cols: 19) and (Rows: 17, Cols: 17) and so on)\n");
    printf("\nMinimum suggested board size is 9x9 and maximum is 31x31(Only for ODD numbers)\n");
    printf("\nEnter the Rows:");
    scanf("%i",&Array->x);
    printf("Enter the Cols:");
    scanf("%i",&Array->y);

    Array->m = Array->x;/*Part of pointed Structure*/
    Array->n = Array->y;/*Part of pointed Structure*/


}

/*Function 4*/
void generate_rand_no( int *a, int*b, char arry[51][51], board Array)/*Generate random number which will be assigned into the 2-D array*/
{

    char x, y;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); /*Generate random number*/
    for(x=0; x < Array.x; x++)
        {
            for(y=0; y < Array.y; y++)
            {
                if (y%2 != 0 && x%2 != 0)/*print number in odd number*/
                    do
                    {
                    arry[x][y]=rand()%7+50; /*range of random number from 2 to 8*/
                    }while((arry[x][y] == arry[x-2][y]) && (arry[x][y] == arry[x-4][y]) || (arry[x][y] == arry[x][y-2])&& (arry[x][y] == arry[x][y-4]));
                            /*Check 3 adjacent number will not appear in both horizontal and vertical axis*/

                else
                arry[x][y]=' ';/*for even number to print a space*/
            }
        }
}

/*Function 5*/
void disp_box(int *a, int *b, char arry[51][51], board Array)/*Display the 2-D array out with random numbers assigned on it randomly*/
{

        Array.rows == Array.m;
        Array.cols == Array.n;
        /*Create the move-able box aorund a number in 2D array*/
        arry[Array.m][Array.n-1] = '|';
        arry[Array.m][Array.n+1] = '|';
        arry[Array.m-1][Array.n] = '=';
        arry[Array.m+1][Array.n] = '=';
}

/*Function 6*/
void disp_arr(board Array, char arry[51][51])/*Display the 2-D array out with random numbers assigned on it randomly*/
{

    /*Used for loops*/
    int c,d;

    printf("\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>NUMBER CRUSH<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n\n");

        for(c=0; c<Array.x; c++)
        {
            printf("\n");

            for(d=0; d<Array.y; d++)
            {
                printf(" %c ", arry[c][d]);

            }

            printf("\n");
        }


}

/*Function 7*/
void disp_menu(int score)/*Display menu to guide players when moving the box*/
{

    printf("\n*Total Score Collected: %i\n\n", score);
    printf("\n*Menu:");
    printf("\n*Press 6 - Move the box RIGHT");
    printf("\n*Press 4 - Move the box LEFT");
    printf("\n*Press 8 - Move the box UP");
    printf("\n*Press 2 - Move the box DOWN");
    printf("\n*Press 5 - Swap the Numbers");
    printf("\n*Press Q - Quit Game or Give Up");
    printf("\nPlease enter your next action <case senstitive>:");

}

/*Function 8*/
void swap_menu()/*Allow players to know what they can do after selecting a number to swap. */
{

        printf("*Menu:\n");
        printf("*Press 6 to move the box to the right\n");
        printf("*Press 4 to move the box to the left\n");
        printf("*Press 8 to move the box up\n");
        printf("*Press 2 to move the box down\n");

}


/*Function 9*/
int move_num(char *input, int *a, int *b ,int score, char arry[51][51], board Array)/*Moving the box to find similar numbers*/
{




    do
    {

        *input=getch(); /*Movement with no "Press enter"*/

            if ( *input == '8' && *a != 1 )/*Box moves UP*/
            {
                system("cls");
                arry[*a+1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b-1]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b+1]=' ';

                *a=*a-2;
                arry[*a-1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a+1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a][*b-1]='|';
                arry[*a][*b+1]='|';

                /*Pass functions*/
                //fflush (stdin);
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                disp_menu(score);

            }
             else if ( *input == '2' && *a != Array.x - 2 )/*Box moves UP*/
            {
                system("cls");
                arry[*a-1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b-1]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b+1]=' ';

                *a=*a+2;
                arry[*a-1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a+1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a][*b-1]='|';
                arry[*a][*b+1]='|';

                /*Pass functions*/
                //fflush (stdin);
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                disp_menu(score);
            }

            else if( *input == '4' && *b != 1 )/*Box moves LEFT*/
            {
                system("cls");
                arry[*a-1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a+1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b+1]=' ';

                *b=*b-2;
                arry[*a-1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a+1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a][*b-1]='|';
                arry[*a][*b+1]='|';

                /*Pass functions*/
                //fflush (stdin);
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                disp_menu(score);
            }

            else if ( *input == '6' && *b != Array.y - 2)/*Box moves RIGHT*/
            {
                system("cls");
                arry[*a-1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a+1][*b]=' ';
                arry[*a][*b-1]=' ';

                *b=*b+2;
                arry[*a-1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a+1][*b]='=';
                arry[*a][*b-1]='|';
                arry[*a][*b+1]='|';

                /*Pass functions*/
                //fflush (stdin);
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                disp_menu(score);
            }
            else if (*input == '5')/*Swap*/
            {
                system("cls");
                return 0;
            }

   }while(*input != 'q');

        system("cls");
        printf("GOOD BYE AND SEE YOU AGAIN!");
        getch();/*Press any key to proceed*/
        exit(0);/*Exit Program*/
        return 0;


}

/*Function 10*/
int swap_num(int *a, int *b,char *Swap,char arry[51][51],int score, int *select, board Array)/*Swap using pointers*/
{
    /*Temporary variable to used and hold when Swapping two numbers*/
    int temp = 0;
    /*Swap using pointers*/
    *Swap = '5';

    /*Pass functions*/
    disp_arr(Array, arry);
    disp_menu(score);
    system("cls");
    disp_arr(Array, arry);
    swap_menu();

    do
    {
            *Swap = getch();

                if (*Swap == '8' && *a != 1)
                {
                    /*Clear the screen*/
                    system("cls");
                    *select = 1;

                    arry[*a-2][*b-1] = '|';
                    arry[*a-2][*b+1] = '|';
                    arry[*a+1][*b] = '=';
                    /*Pass functions*/
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    /*To clear the argument in fflush() like memory*/
                    //fflush(stdin);
                }
                else if (*Swap == '2' && *b != Array.x-2)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    *select = 2;
                    arry[*a-2][*b-1] = '|';
                    arry[*a-2][*b+1] = '|';

                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    //fflush(stdin);
                }
                else if (*Swap == '4' && *b != 1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    *select = 3;

                    arry[*a][*b-3] = ' ';
                    arry[*a+2][*b-1]=' ';
                    arry[*b-2][*b-1]=' ';
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                }
                else if (*Swap == '6' && *b != Array.y-2)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    *select = 4;

                    arry[*a][*b+3] = ' ';
                    arry[*a+2][*b-1]=' ';
                    arry[*a-2][*b-1]=' ';
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    //fflush(stdin);
                }

                if (*select == 1)
                {
                    temp = arry[*a][*b];
                    arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a-2][*b];
                    arry[*a-2][*b] = temp;
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    return 0;
                }

                else if (*select == 2)
                {
                    temp = arry[*a][*b];
                    arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a+2][*b];
                    arry[*a+2][*b] = temp;
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    return 0;
                }

                else if (*select == 3)
                {
                    temp = arry[*a][*b];
                    arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a][*b-2];
                    arry[*a][*b-2] = temp;
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    return 0;
                }

                else if (*select == 4)
                {
                    temp = arry[*a][*b];
                    arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a][*b+2];
                    arry[*a][*b+2] = temp;
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    return 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

    }while (*Swap != 'q');

        system("cls");
        return 0;

}

/*Function 11*/
/*To verify the matching numbers*/
int verify(int *a, int *b, char c, char d, char arry[51][51],int score, int *valid, board Array)
{

    int temp=0;

    for ( c = 0 ;c < Array.x ; c++)

        for ( d = 0 ;d < Array.y ; d++ )
        {
            if (c %2 != 0 && d %2 != 0)
            {
                if (arry[c][d] == arry[c][d+2] && arry[c][d] == arry[c][d-2])/*Clear or boom 3 same numbers horizontally*/

                {
                     *valid = 1;
                    /*For every 3 same numbers matched, 3 points will be given*/
                    score+=3;
                    /*Clears the box after swapping*/
                    arry[*a][*b-1]  =' ';
                    arry[*a][*b+1]  =' ';
                    arry[*a-1][*b]  =' ';
                    arry[*a+1][*b]  =' ';
                    /*Make the box to show at the 3 identical match of numbers*/
                    arry[c][d-1]    ='|';
                    arry[c-1][d-2]  ='=';
                    arry[c+1][d-2]  ='=';
                    arry[c-1][d]    ='=';
                    arry[c+1][d]    ='=';
                    arry[c-1][d+2]  ='=';
                    arry[c+1][d+2]  ='=';
                    arry[c][d+1]    ='|';
                    arry[c][d-3]    ='|';
                    arry[c][d+3]    ='|';
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    printf("Awesome!!!!\n");
                    printf("Press any key to continue crushing!...\n");
                    /*To produce a beep sound when matching 3 same numbers*/
                    printf("\a\n");
                    /*Press anykey to proceed to next step*/
                    getch();
                    /*Clear the 3 identical number and also the indicator*/
                    arry[c][d-1]    =' ';
                    arry[c-1][d-2]  =' ';
                    arry[c+1][d-2]  =' ';
                    arry[d-1][d]    =' ';
                    arry[c+1][d]    =' ';
                    arry[c-1][d+2]  =' ';
                    arry[c+1][d+2]  =' ';
                    arry[c][d+1]    =' ';
                    arry[c][d-3]    =' ';
                    arry[c][d+3]    =' ';
                    arry[c][d]      =' ';
                    arry[c][d+2]    =' ';
                    arry[c][d-2]    =' ';
                    /*Clear the screen*/
                    system("cls");
                    /*Pass Functions*/
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);

                    for ( c = c ; c > 1; c-- )
                    {
                         /*The numbers above will replace the empty space*/
                        arry[c][d]=arry[c-2][d];
                        arry[c][d+2]=arry[c-2][d+2];
                        arry[c][d-2]=arry[c-2][d-2];
                    }
                        /*Generate new random number after the number drops*/
                        arry[1][d]=rand()%7 +50;
                        arry[1][d+2]=rand()%7 +50;
                        arry[1][d-2]=rand()%7 +50;
                        system("cls");
                        disp_arr(Array, arry);


                }

                else if (arry[c][d] == arry[c+2][d] && arry[c][d] == arry[c-2][d])/*Clear or boom 3 same numbers vertically*/
                {

                    *valid = 1;
                     /*For every 3 same numbers matched, 3 points will be given*/
                    score+=3;
                    /*Clears the box after swapping*/
                    arry[*a][*b-1]=' ';
                    arry[*a][*b+1]=' ';
                    arry[*a-1][*b]=' ';
                    arry[*a+1][*b]=' ';
                    /*Make the box to show at the 3 identical match of numbers*/
                    arry[c][d-1]  ='|';
                    arry[c][d+1]  ='|';
                    arry[c-2][d-1]='|';
                    arry[c-2][d+1]='|';
                    arry[c+2][d-1]='|';
                    arry[c+2][d+1]='|';
                    arry[c+1][d]  ='=';
                    arry[c-1][d]  ='=';
                    arry[c+3][d]  ='=';
                    arry[c-3][d]  ='=';

                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);
                    printf("Awesome!!!\n");
                    printf("Press any key to continue crushing!...\n");
                    /*To produce a beep sound when matching 3 same numbers*/
                    printf("\a\n");
                    /*Press anykey to proceed to next step*/
                    getch();
                    /*Clear the 3 identical number and also the indicator*/
                    arry[c][d-1]  =' ';
                    arry[c][d+1]  =' ';
                    arry[c-2][d-1]=' ';
                    arry[c-2][d+1]=' ';
                    arry[c+2][d-1]=' ';
                    arry[c+2][d+1]=' ';
                    arry[c+1][d]  =' ';
                    arry[c-1][d]  =' ';
                    arry[c+3][d]  =' ';
                    arry[c-3][d]  =' ';
                    system("cls");
                    disp_arr(Array, arry);


                    for ( c = c ; c > 1; c-- )
                    {
                        /*The numbers above will drop replace the empty space*/
                        arry[c+2][d]=arry[c-4][d];
                        arry[c-2][d]=arry[c][d];
                        arry[c][d]=arry[c-2][d];
                    }
                        /*Generate new random number after the number drops*/
                        arry[1][d]=rand()%7 +50;
                        arry[3][d]=rand()%7 +50;
                        arry[5][d]=rand()%7 +50;
                        system("cls");
                        disp_arr(Array, arry);


                }

            }

        }
    return score;/*Return to score*/

}

/*Function 12*/
/*check for invalid moves*/
int invalidmove(int *a, int *b, char arry[51][51],int *select,int *valid, board Array)
{


    int temp=0;
    /*Clear the screen*/
    system("cls");
    /*Pass functions*/
    disp_arr(Array, arry);
    printf("WRONG Move!! Try Again!");
    getch();
    /*To clear memory*/
    fflush(stdin);

            if (*select == 1)
            {
                temp = arry[*a][*b];
                arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a-2][*b];
                arry[*a-2][*b] = temp;
                system("cls");
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                return 0;
            }

            else if (*select == 2)
            {
                temp = arry[*a][*b];
                arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a+2][*b];
                arry[*a+2][*b] = temp;
                system("cls");
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                return 0;
            }

            else if (*select == 3)
            {
                temp = arry[*a][*b];
                arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a][*b-2];
                arry[*a][*b-2] = temp;
                system("cls");
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                return 0;
            }

            else if (*select == 4)
            {
                temp = arry[*a][*b];
                arry[*a][*b] = arry[*a][*b+2];
                arry[*a][*b+2] = temp;
                system("cls");
                disp_arr(Array, arry);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
            return 0;
            }

}

/*Function 13*/
/*Save read-file*/
/*void save(char username[20], int *score)
{

    FILE *NumberCrush_XY = fopen("NumberCrush_XY.txt","a");

    fprintf(NumberCrush_XY,"%s\t\t%i\t\n",username, &score);

    fclose(NumberCrush_XY);

}

/*Function 14*/
/*Read save file after restart the program*/
/*void read_save()
{
    FILE *NumberCrush_XY = fopen("NumberCrush_XY.txt","r");

    char username[20];
    int score = 0;

    system("cls");
    if (NumberCrush_XY == NULL)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS ARE FOUND!");
    }

    printf("\t\t LIST OF PREVIOUS PLAYER\n\n");

    while(fscanf(NumberCrush_XY, "%s%i",username, &score) == 2)
    {
        printf("\tPlayer Name:%s\t Score:%i\n",username, score);
    }

    printf("Bye, see you again next time!! Press any key to Exit!");
    getch();

}
*/

/*Main*/
int main()
{

    /*Variables*/
    char arry[51][51];
    int m;
    int stopMove=0;
    int n;
    int c,d;
    int score=0;
    int select = 0;
    int valid=0;
    char input;
    char username[100];
    char id[100];
    board Array;



    /*Color for background*/
    system("COLOR 80");
    /*Pass Functions*/
    disp_welcome_msg();

    printf("\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR USERNAME BELOW\n");
    printf("\nUSERNAME:");
    scanf("%s", &username);
    printf("\nGood day, %s. Hope you can CRUSH the numbers easily!!!...");


    FILE * scoreboard=fopen("scoreboard.txt","");

        fprintf(scoreboard,"%s  %i\t\n",username, score);

        scoreboard = fopen("scoreboard.txt","r");

        printf("\n\n*************List of Previous Players*****************\n");

        if (scoreboard == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nNo scores found.\n");
            }


            while(fscanf(scoreboard,"%s %i",username, &score) == 2)
            {
                printf("Name: %s\t\t",username);
                printf("Scores: %i\n", score);
            }
    fclose(scoreboard);
    printf("\n");

    /*Pause system and press any ket to proceed*/
    system("pause");
    /*clear the screen*/
    system("cls");


    system("COLOR 08");
    board_size(&Array);

    /*Pointed structure in choosing board size*/
    m = Array.x;
    n = Array.y;

    system("cls");
    disp_ready_msg();
    system("pause");
    system("cls");


    system("COLOR F0");
    /*Pass functions*/
    generate_rand_no(&m, &n, arry, Array);
    disp_box(&m, &n, arry, Array);
    disp_arr(Array, arry);
    disp_menu(score);



    /*Loop the pass functions and enable the box to move around the board with no limits*/
    do
    {
    move_num(&input, &m, &n ,score, arry, Array);
    swap_num(&m, &n, &input, arry, score, &select, Array);
    score=verify(&m, &n, c, d, arry, score, &valid, Array);

        valid = 0;
        if (valid == 0)
                {
                    invalidmove(&m,&n,arry,&select,&valid, Array);
                }



    }while (input != 'Q' || input != 'q');
    system("cls");
    /*Pass functions for save and read file*/
    //save(username, score);
    //read_save();
}
```

Comment: sorry if my full codes are too long.. i am sincerely want to know my mistake on my readfile. So fed up of that error. 

SO DO HELP ME! thanks

Comment: does the username string contain space?

Comment: If your first `fopen()` and `fprintf()` successful?

Comment: no. it does not contain. *sorry i am still beginner into c programming

Comment: yup. it can print up the name well but not for the score which i do not know why.

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: how do i solve this?? im still a beginner in this btw.

Comment: Can you provide the scores file too? So we can check the data you're trying to read

Comment: how to add txt file here? sorry im still a beginner to stackoverflow too @@

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file a second time, without closing it first. Since Standard I/O is buffered, the file will likely appear empty when read. What you should do:

```
  scoreboard = fopen ("scoreboard.txt", "w");
  if (scoreboard != NULL) {
    do the writing
    fclose (scoreboard);
  } else {
    scream and die
  }

  scoreboard = fopen ("scoreboard.txt", "r");
  if (scoreboard != NULL) {
    do the reading
    fclose (scoreboard);
  } else {
    scream and die
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> May I know whats the mistake I made in here?

- You commented out (the call to) the `save` function.
- Invocation `save(username, score);` and declaration `void save(char username[20], int *score)` are incompatible.
- Given above declaration, in `fprintf(NumberCrush_XY,"%s\t\t%i\t\n",username, &score);` the `&score` is wrong, `*score` would be correct, while with the declaration `void save(char username[20], int score)`, `fprintf(..., score);` would.
- ...